# Can't set up my sites in SharePoint 2010

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync, my-site

I'd like to run MySite in my sharepoint 2010 instance. I'm following the article from TechNet from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721052.aspx) for creating Profile Service Application. I'm creating profile service application and then MySite site collection. I'm stuck in point 4 in section *Configure My Site settings for the User Profile service application* from the first technet article. When I'm clicking *Setup My Sites*, I'm getting following error:

```
Cannot create an object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.LocStringId' from its string representation 'SiteAdminPersonalSite_SocialSecurityTrimmerEnabledSectionTitle_Text' for the 'TitleLocId' property.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.



Correlation ID: 1c208017-27ae-432d-a4f6-f3077cdf1a4e

Date and Time: 10/11/2011 2:20:26 PM
```

Any ideas what can cause that error, because I have no idea.

### **Edit:**

It seems that my problem might be connected with fact, that I can't start User Profile Synchronization Service. After creating *User Profile Service Application*, with new Application pool and SPS_FARM user (which I added earlier into farm administrators group), when I try to start synchronization service, it's starting for couple of minutes and then it's not started. There is a message logged after failure:

```
Maximum number of retries done for starting FIM SpService. Please look at ULS logs and event viewer to look for the root cause of the failure.
```

No idea what and where to look for.

Comment: The first step is (always) to check the logs about the given Correlation ID. And since 90% for the MySite-Provisioning-Erros are cause by missing permission for service accounts I would start to double check these...

Comment: Could you point some locations what accounts/where should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of problems starting user profile synchronization are the farm account permissions, which needs the "log on locally" right and to be local admin. on the machine running the synchronization while the service is provisioned.

The definitive source of information on this topic is Spence Harbar's blog:

[Rational Guide to implementing SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx)

[“Stuck on Starting”: Common Issues with SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx)

Comment: I followed Spence's guide in fresh installation of sharepoint with no success. I'll try again when we will be able to connect to copy of production active directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the same thing, and am getting the same error when configuring My Sites.  But I DID resolve the issue with User Profile Synchronization not running.  You will need to apply special permissions to the farm account using ADSIEDIT.  In particular, it needs permissions to replicate AD information.  This article provides very detailed and easy to follow instructions:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh296982.aspx